# JS: Filter object array for partial matches

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to filter for those objects, which matches for a search string?

```
const arr = [
    { title: 'Just an example' },
    { title: 'Another exam'},
    { title: 'Something different'}
]
```

I tried this

```
arr.filter(x => { return x.title === searchStr });
```

But this will filter only exact matches, but I need to find all partial matches. `let searchStr = 'exam'` should give me two objects (first and second), `let searchStr = 'examp'` should give me only one object as the result.

Comment: `x.title.indexOf(searchStr) !== -1`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From your question I will assume you also want to match both uppercase and lowercase versions of your string, so here RegExps are the right (but not the only) choice.

#### RegExp solution:

First, define a case-insensitive [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the [`i` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Case), outside of the loop (this avoids re-creating a new RegExp instance on each iteration):

```
 const regexp = new RegExp(searchStr, 'i');
```

Then you can filter the list with [RegExp#test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) ([String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) would work too):

```
arr.filter(x => regexp.test(x.title))
```

#### String#includes solution:

You could also use the [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method of `String`, converting both strings to lowercase before comparing them:

```
arr.filter(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchStr.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: There is one closing bracket too much: `arr.filter(x => regexp.test(x)))` and for this question you have to use `x.title` instead of `x`... ;-)

Comment: Awesome solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using ES6, use the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to test for the substring.

```
arr.filter(x => x.title.includes(searchStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the indexOf and also add toLowerCase() method to increase the possibility of a match

```
myArr.filter(function(x) { 
    return x.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```