# Search inside a JSON Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem concern search JSON string and i have JSON string

```
{"userDetail":[
 {
   "Name": "Scottic Mangry",
   "Age" : "12", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Joneson Mangly",
   "Age" : "18", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Saoyu Wang",
   "Age" : "15", 
 },
]}
```

And data search

```
let searchObj = "Mang"
```

I need a result

```
 {
   "Name": "Scottic Mangry",
   "Age" : "12", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Joneson Mangly",
   "Age" : "18", 
 }
```

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Comment: `filter` and `includes` can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter object array based on string array "with partial match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250401/filter-object-array-based-on-string-array-with-partial-match)

Comment: also: [JS: Filter object array for partial matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035717/js-filter-object-array-for-partial-matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```js
let data = {
    "userDetail":[
     {
       "Name": "Scottic Mangry",
       "Age" : "12", 
     },
     {
       "Name": "Joneson Mangly",
       "Age" : "18", 
     },
     {
       "Name": "Saoyu Wang",
       "Age" : "15", 
     },
    ]
}

let needle = "Mang";
let result = data['userDetail'].filter(el => el.Name.includes(needle));
console.log(result);
```

`needle` is the string we are searching for inside the `Name` property of the `data.userDetail` object

`includes` is case sensitive, so if you want to match results regardless of case it's easiest to lowercase everything first

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `Array.filter`, `Array.values` and `includes`

```js
const data = {"userDetail":[
 {
   "Name": "Scottic Mangry",
   "Age" : "12", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Joneson Mangly",
   "Age" : "18", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Saoyu Wang",
   "Age" : "15", 
 },
]}


const search = (data, search) => data.filter(d => Object.values(d).some(v => v.includes(search)))

console.log(search(data.userDetail, "Mang"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As *cmgchess* say in comments
Using *filter* and *includes* would do the job for you:
to make it more declarative and readable I put it inside a function called `findName`

```js
const objs = {
  "userDetail": [{
      "Name": "Scottic Mangry",
      "Age": "12",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Joneson Mangly",
      "Age": "18",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Saoyu Wang",
      "Age": "15",
    },
  ]
}

function findName(name) {
  return objs.userDetail.filter(user => user.Name.includes(name))
}
let searchObj = "Mang";
console.log(findName(searchObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple filter.

```
({"userDetail":[
 {
   "Name": "Scottic Mangry",
   "Age" : "12", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Joneson Mangly",
   "Age" : "18", 
 },
 {
   "Name": "Saoyu Wang",
   "Age" : "15", 
 },
]}).userDetail.filter(e=>e.Name.includes("Mang"))
```